# mongoose set: toLower not working on nested properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to normalize email addresses to lowercase before they are saved in the database. Setters on mongoose models are great for that and they work on simple models. However, when I try to set the toLower setter on a nested object where email is stored inside "owner" I get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

function toLower (v) {
  return v.toLowerCase();
}

This crashes:

```
var BusinessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {
        email:  { type: String, required: 'Email adres mag niet leeg zijn.', set: toLower, get: toLower, index: { unique: true } },
        password: { type: String, required: 'Wachtwoord mag niet leeg zijn.' }
    }
});
```

This works:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, set: toLower } 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're also using `toLower` as a getter, it's first called with a value of `undefined` when creating a new doc, then called again with the actual value.  Regardless, your `toLower` function needs to protect itself so that it can be called with any value, not just strings.

So something like:

```javascript
function toLower (v) {
    if ('string' != typeof v) v = '';
    return v.toLowerCase();
}
```

If you don't need the getter side of this, you could also just use the built-in [`lowercase`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-lowercase) setter:

```javascript
var BusinessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {
        email:  { 
            type: String, 
            required: 'Email adres mag niet leeg zijn.', 
            lowercase: true,
            index: { unique: true }
        },
        password: { type: String, required: 'Wachtwoord mag niet leeg zijn.' }
    }
});
```